# How to prevent ScrollView to automatically show items added on top of inner ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a bidirectional scrolling list of items and we need to add items to the head of the array, but the ScrollView is automatically scrolling down (probably to preserve the contentOffset?) and I can't achieve what I want, which would be that the items are ready to be displayed but only if the user scrolls up.

I'm not sure if there is a way to "fix" this by fiddling with ScrollView or if wrapping UIScrollView is just the easier way for now.

Snippet to reproduce:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var list = [1, 2, 3]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ScrollView {
        LazyVStack {
          ForEach(Array(zip(list.indices, list)), id: \.0) { index, element in
            Text("\(element)")
          }
        }
      }
      .frame(maxHeight: 300)
      Button(action: {
        list = [Int.random(in: 1...1000)] + list
      }) {
        Text("Add")
          .font(.title)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this `list.insert(Int.random(in: 1...1000), at: 0)`

Comment: @mahan thanks for the suggestion but it's not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

We can try this :

1. We need to read the offset of `ScrollView`'s content. We'll use `PreferenceKey`.

```
private struct Offset: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGPoint = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGPoint, nextValue: () -> CGPoint) {}
}
```

2. We need to store the new elements (when user taps on "Add") until they are added (when user scrolls to the top) :

```
struct MutableScrollView: View {
    @State private var list = Array(1 ... 100)
    @State private var elementsToAdd = Array<Int>()
    @State private var onTop: Bool = true
```

3. `onClick` is called when the user taps the Button. `offsetChanged` when we scroll.

```
    func addNewElements() {
        if onTop {
            list = elementsToAdd + list
            elementsToAdd.removeAll()
        }
    }
    func onClick() {
        elementsToAdd.append(Int.random(in: 100 ... 1000))
        addNewElements()
    }
    func offsetChanged(_ offset: CGPoint) {
        onTop = offset.y >= 0
        addNewElements()
    }
```

4. The View :

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.preference(
                        key: Offset.self,
                        value: geometry.frame(in: .named("scrollView")).origin
                    )
                }.frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(Array(zip(list.indices, list)), id: \.1) { _, element in
                        Text("\(element)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: 300)
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scrollView")
            .onPreferenceChange(Offset.self) { offsetChanged($0) }
            Button(action: onClick) {
                Text("Add")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's happening with this code is that all items in `elementsToAdd` get added at the same time, pushing down the scroll view all of a sudden, which is not the desired effect.

Comment: @MattiaC. `ScrollViewReader` and `scrollView.scrollTo()` allow to scroll to a subview. But not to change precisely content's offset (CGFloat). So I think you should wrap UIScrollView (to change the offset after adding an element).